# progressbar not animated when views are added

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-progressbar

My progressbar is not animated, when I add dynamical imageviews to my tablerows

My xml looks as follows:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
tools:context=".activities.xyActivity">

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:indeterminate="true" />

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/progressBar">

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="1">    
    </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

When I open my Activity I add a certain number of tableRows to my tablelayout. After that I start a AsyncTask to pull data from my database and add pictures to the rows. During that time, I want to show an animated progressbar. The progressbar is shown correctly and also disappears when the tablelayout is loaded, but it is not animated. Could someone please help me to figure out what the problem is?

The Progressbar is animated correctly when no tableRows are added to the tablelayout or when no imageviews are added to the tablerows. So the problem must be caused by the adding the imageviews

My Activity code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.shelf);

    Intent clickedShelf = getIntent();
    shelf_id = clickedShelf.getIntExtra("shelfId", 0);
    noofBoards = clickedShelf.getExtras().getInt("noofBoards");

    tableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);
    scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
    pb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

    for (int i = 0; i < noofBoards; i++) {
        tableRow = new TableRow(this);
        tableRow.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        tableRow.setId(i+1);
        tableRow.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.shelfboard);
        tableRow.setPadding(20, 0, 20, 0);
        tableRow.setOnClickListener(this);

        tableLayout.addView(tableRow);

    }
    if (noofBoards!=0) {
       new ArticleDataProductAsync(pb).execute("someParams");
   }
   else {
       TextView v = new TextView(thisvariable);
       v.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
       v.setText("no data saved yet");
       tableLayout.addView(v);
   }
}    


    public class ArticleDataProductAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
     ProgressBar pb;
     public ArticleDataProductAsync (ProgressBar pb) {
        this.pb=pb;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        //database connection is started
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        //result is converted to ArrayList

        if (adpList.isEmpty()) {
            TextView v = new TextView(thisvariable);
            v.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
            v.setText("no products saved yet");
            tableLayout.addView(v);
        }

        else {

        for (int i = 0; i < adpList.size(); i++) {
            //find corresponding tablerow and add new imageview for each object and set imagebitmap to it

               imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        //start new Intent
                    }
                });
            }
        }
            pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Show your ProgressBar on your AsyncTask with the onPreExecute method or Add this method on your ArticleDataProductAsync Class, like so.

```
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but adding this method hasn't changed anything. It is still not animated...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to identify the problem. I used

> Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());

before I set the bitmap to my ImageView.This blocked my ImageView

I found an answer here: https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html